# Why ASP.NET did not working correctly

Tags: asp.net

Why ASP.NET did not working correctly using IE11 and showing "Page cannot be displayed" error using other version of IE.

Hi,

I'm currently doing my internship and need to finish the other's intern works using ASP.NET and this is my first time using ASP.NET.

My laptop is working on Windows 10, and using IE11. I already add ip address into the iplisten and also edit the host file by adding my laptop ip address and ::1 but it still not working. I googled everything and still not find the right answer for my problems. Please someone help me.

[This is what it tells me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6ZHD.png)

Thank you.

Comment: looks like only directory browsing happening.. go to project properties and create virtual directory and update the application pool correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I already create the new virtual directory and update the application pool correctly but it didn't works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your IIS (Internet Information Server). If you IIS server not run, you cann't see this page. uninstall/install or modify your visual studio. Successfully Instal IIS server, you will working asp.net easily.

Comment: After I modify the visual studio, I cannot connect the server. This is the error message that I've got:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: please check SQL server and read this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified/

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution. I installed the new sql server with advanced tools. Before this, I just installed the sql server management studio and not the sql server express.